# Java delete and rename file issue

Tags: java

Method below has function to simply move files from the "working" to the "move" directory which paths it receives through the method call. It all works, but for the case when file name has name with two extensions (like .xml.md5) where the .renameTo method returns false. Is there a way to alter the below code so it would work regardless of the OS that it's run on. (Currently it is the Windows)

```
public void moveToDir(String workDir, String moveDir) throws Exception {
    File tempFile = new File(workDir);
    File[] filesInWorkingDir = tempFile.listFiles();
    for (File file : filesInWorkingDir) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
        if (new File(moveDir + File.separator + file.getName()).exists()) 
            new File(moveDir + File.separator + file.getName()).delete();
        System.out.println(moveDir + File.separator + file.getName());
        Boolean renameSuccessful = file.renameTo(new File(moveDir + File.separator + file.getName()));
        if (!renameSuccessful) throw new Exception("Can't move file to " + moveDir +": " + file.getPath());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that you have write permissions for the file that you want to move and the directory you want to move it to? (file.canWrite()) Maybe this can be a permission issue...

Comment: did u try FileUtils.moveFile()

Comment: @Arasu - I did try, this is the exception: "Failed to delete original file 'working\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xml.md5' after copy to 'successful\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xml.md5'"

Comment: @Alderath - Yes, I have full permission on file system. This is my local workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have simplified your code and added a check if delete was successful. Try it.

```
public void moveToDir(String workDir, String moveDir) {
  for (File file : new File(workDir).listFiles()) {
      System.out.println(file.getName());
      final File toFile = new File(moveDir, file.getName());
      if (toFile.exists() && !toFile.delete())
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot delete " + toFile);
      System.out.println(toFile);
      if (!file.renameTo(toFile))
        throw new RuntimeException(
          "Can't move file to " + moveDir +": " + file.getPath());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marko, it works now. Can you be so kind and tell me what I did wrong and what caused the method not work as expected?

Comment: It's hard to say, I just cleaned it up. It could be the way that you instantiated the same File many times, maybe one of them was not right; could be that you combined the paths explicitly by String concatenanion and I used the appropriate constructor.